# How to use value of a cookie in html code?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, cookies

I need to retrieve the value of a specific cookie then show it and also use it in my HTML code.

My code is as following, value is shown after "Value is:" message but I am not sure how to have it as parameter of myfunc function.

```
  <% Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                if (cookies[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("MyCookie")) {

                    out.println("Value is:" + cookies[i].getValue());
                }
            }
        %>
        <form id="everything" onsubmit="myfunc(VALUE NEED TO BE HERE)">
             ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
   String myCookie = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("MyCookie")) {
                myCookie = cookies[i].getValue();
                out.println("Value is:" + cookies[i].getValue());
            }
        }
    %>
    <form id="everything" onsubmit="myfunc('<%=myCookie%>')">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a variable in Java code within a JSP file:

```
<% int i = 4; %>
```

you can use it using the following tag:

```
<%= i %>
```